# I need to find the 9th positive integer that is a multiple of 4, 13, 14, 26, and 50 using python:

Tags: python-3.6

## Why doesn't this code work? I am getting a continuous loop...

```
solution = 0
multiple = 0
max_bound = 100000
i = 1

while i < max_bound:
    if (i % 4 == 0) and (i % 13 == 0) and (i % 14) and (i % 26 == 0) and (i % 50 == 0):
        multiple += 1
        if multiple == 9:
            solution = i 
            break 
    i += 1 

if multiple == 9:
  print("#1 : 9th Multiple ::", "Correct." if solution == 81900 else ("Wrong: " + str(solution)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed the **14** verification you used `(1 % 14)` instead of `(i % 14 == 0)` which returns 0(**False**) when the number is divisible by 14 instead of **True** and with the **and** operator it doesn't enter the if statement.

```
solution = 0
multiple = 0
max_bound = 100000
i = 1

while i < max_bound:
    if (i % 4 == 0) and (i % 13 == 0) and (i % 14 == 0) and (i % 26 == 0) and (i % 50 == 0):
        multiple += 1
        if multiple == 9:
            solution = i
            break
    i += 1

if multiple == 9:
    print("#1 : 9th Multiple ::", "Correct." if solution == 81900 else ("Wrong: " + str(solution)))
```